# I don't get any altitude data (GPS Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

I am doing a GPS app, with latitude, longitude, speed, altitude...but I don't get any data for this one. I always get 1.0 as a value. (With the speed it happens the same).

I tried with the simulator of GPX in Eclipse (DDMS) and **on the terminal** (KML simulator, not on the street)...but it always shows 0.0 or 1.0.

[image]

My code is the following:

```
private Location currentLoc;
private Location previousLoc;
```

The criteria for the GPS...

```
    // Criteria object is optional. Will return value representing "GPS"
    Criteria oGPSSettings = new Criteria();
    oGPSSettings.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    oGPSSettings.setSpeedRequired(true);
    oGPSSettings.setAltitudeRequired(true);
    oGPSSettings.setBearingRequired(false);
    oGPSSettings.setCostAllowed(false);
    oGPSSettings.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
```

When a new location is recieved...

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLoc = location;
    String sText = "Altitude: " + currentLoc.getAltitude();
    txtOutput.setText(sText);
}

// sets this location as last location.
previousLoc = currentLoc;

}
```

I removed from the code things like displaying latitude, longitude...right now I'll show only altitude.

**The question is**: Why do you think is it happening this? The latitude and longitude works fine, but not the altitude. Maybe is it a hardware issue? Because the code seems correct, I think. Only with the getAltitude function should works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi. I thought it was clear, sorry. I editted my question being more specific. Greetings.

Comment: Could you truncate your code to the bare minimum to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Of course. Now is shorter and more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask for "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" in your manifest?
also try changing ACCURACY_FINE to ACCURACY_HIGH